# Custom scoop border style - responsive, Custom & dynamic border style - fit in height, Custom border corner - double stroke

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-shapes

Is there any way to make custom scoop border style in CSS or jQuery?

Like the image below:

[image: Example image of border style]

Comment: Hey Atriar. Welcome to SO. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide a more robust description of what you're looking to get help with. It's also beneficial to include all of the code you've tried yourself.

Comment: You might want to look into `border-image`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Comment: Finally i got it to work - here is details - https://github.com/atiar-cse/Custom-scoop-border-style---responsive-Custom-dynamic-border-style---fit-in-height-Custom-border

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fiddle ...http://jsfiddle.net/zjw3pg2e/5/
Does this work for you?

```
body {
    background: #D8D8D8;
}
.corner {
    background:white;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;    
    position:absolute;
}
#sw {
    left: -2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
    background:#D8D8D8;
}
#se {
    right: -2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    border-left: 2px solid white;
    background:#D8D8D8;
}
#nw {
    left: -2px;
    top: -2px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    border-right: 2px solid white; 
    background:#D8D8D8;
}
#ne {
    right: -2px;
    top: -2px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white; 
    border-left: 2px solid white;
    background:#D8D8D8;
}

.box {
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border: solid 2px white;
    background:#D8D8D8;
    border-radius: 5px -5px 5px 5px;
}
.box2 {
    position:relative;
    height:160px;
    width:160px;
    overflow:hidden;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
.box2:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    margin:-20px;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    border-radius:100%;
    background:#D8D8D8;
    box-shadow:160px 0 0 #D8D8D8,
    0 160px 0 #D8D8D8,
    160px 160px 0 #D8D8D8,
    0 0 0 500px white;   
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div id="ne"  class="corner"></div> <!--ne, nw, se, sw, are the corners-->
    <div id="nw" class="corner"></div>  <!--of first object-->
    <div id="se" class="corner"></div>
    <div id="sw" class="corner"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>  <!--box2 is the inner border object-->
</div>
```

Note that for the encompassing box, `ne`, `nw`, `se`, `sw` are the inverted corners.

For `box2`, It is rather difficult to explain what is going on. My suggestion is to play around with the colours of the box-shadow, as well as the pixel positions, to understand how the box-shadow gives the illusion of an inverted border.

Once you get the hang of it, it's really easy to change the dimensions so that it fits your liking.

Comment: Hi Bolboa, your idea is also good but it seems difficult to add the content. But Finally i got it to work - here is details - https://github.com/atiar-cse/Custom-scoop-border-style---responsive-Custom-dynamic-border-style---fit-in-height-Custom-border